# DataRow Field Cast From Variable

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

Is it possible to cast a type from a variable?  I'm extracting data from a spreadsheet into a class, but because some columns are strings, and others DateTime, I really want a do-all command, that I don't need to map everything manually.

What I have so far:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo pinfo in asset.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    string columnType = (from DataColumn column in data.Columns where column.ColumnName == pinfo.Name select column).First().DataType.ToString();
    pinfo.SetValue(asset, row.Field<columnType>(pinfo.Name));
}
```

At the moment, it doesn't like `row.Field<columnType>()`, because it's not a real type.

Is it possible to do something like the above, where I'm getting the type contained in a column, and casting this to retrieve the data for that column?  I'm in this situation, as I want to retrieve anything using the following statement, regardless of whether it's a string, int or DateTime.

```
var foo = row.Field<string>("Column Name");
```

Is there any generic command I can use?  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PropertyInfo.SetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194291%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) accepts value as object. If your DataTable has column of appropriate type, then just get column value with `row[columnName]` which also will be returned as object, and use it to set property value:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo pinfo in asset.GetType().GetProperties())
{
     pinfo.SetValue(asset, row[pinfo.Name]);
}
```

Sample: consider you have class

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And you have DataTable which has columns with appropriate types:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
dt.Rows.Add(1, "Bob");
dt.Rows.Add(2, "John");
```

Then filling user from DataTable will look like:

```
var user = new User();
var row = dt.Rows[0];

foreach (PropertyInfo pinfo in user.GetType().GetProperties())
    pinfo.SetValue(user, row[pinfo.Name]);
```

NOTE: You can skip properties which don't have appropriate type, also you can handle case when there is no column with property name:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo pinfo in user.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    if (!dt.Columns.Contains(pinfo.Name) || 
         dt.Columns[pinfo.Name].DataType != pinfo.PropertyType)
        continue;

    pinfo.SetValue(user, row[pinfo.Name]);
}
```

Comment: That's great, thanks Sergey. A question if I may, If my class only has strings, is it possible to perform what you've done above, and still extract DateTime, but into a string property?

Comment: @Mark converting to string is easy :) `row[pinfo.Name].ToString()` you probably will need to add null-check if table can contain null values